# No http handler was found for request type 'POST'

Tags: .net, http, post, handler

This error comes up when I submit a page to load up a .net chart control. I have the http handler in my web.config below. FOr whateve reason it doesnt seem to work.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
  <add verb="GET" path="FtbWebResource.axd" type="FreeTextBoxControls.AssemblyResourceHandler, FreeTextBox" />
  <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Any ideas why this error would come up? Im stumped on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the handler in the `<system.webServer>` section of the web.config for IIS 7.

Answer (score 11):

Just to help make things clear, because they weren't clear to me;

chopps' answer: "I needed to add the handler in the section of the web.config for IIS 7"

means the handler needed to also be in the `system.webServer` section in the `web.config`.

Per Todd:

```
<add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" 
type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, 
System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
```

Comment: <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />

Comment: I had the handler, but was listing only GET and HEAD as verbs! Oops! Added POST and I'm golden.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to Classic .NET AppPool in IIS worked for me - as recommended in chopps' comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help make things clear, because they weren't clear to me;

chopps' anser: "I needed to add the handler in the section of the web.config for IIS 7"

means the handler needed to also be in the system.webServer section in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Classic .NET AppPool in IIS worked for me！ I met the issue while migrating the web site from IIS 6 to IIS 10.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm...maybe `<remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>` makes your server no longer respond to POST requests?  Try commenting that out, and see if it's overriding the `add` lines.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but no luck.

Comment: ok..switching to Classic .NET AppPool in IIS clears this up. I dont't know why it doesnt work in Integrated mode.